# Add FLS to custom fields of Activity (Task/Event) in bulk from workbench

Tags: metadata-api, custom-field, workbench, activity

[image: FLS Setting Page for Custom Fields]

I created about a 100 custom fields for Activities in bulk using metadata API via workbench. Now I have to manually Set FLS for each custom field one by one for Activity from the UI, which is a time taking exercise.

I thought I can try using workbench to deploy field permissions to all the custom fields in bulk.

Here are the manifest files.

**package.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>Activity.custom_field_1__c</members>
        <name>CustomField</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>Activity.custom_field_2__c</members>
        <name>CustomField</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>Activity.custom_field_3__c</members>
        <name>CustomField</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>Activity.custom_field_4__c</members>
        <name>CustomField</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>Activity.custom_field_5__c</members>
        <name>CustomField</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>Admin</members>
        <name>Profile</name>
    </types>
    <version>58.0</version>
</Package>
```

**Activity.object**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomObject xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <fields>
        <fullName>custom_field_1__c</fullName>
        <externalId>false</externalId>
        <label>custom-field-1</label>
        <length>255</length>
        <required>false</required>
        <type>Text</type>
        <unique>false</unique>
    </fields>
    <fields>
        <fullName>custom_field_2__c</fullName>
        <externalId>false</externalId>
        <label>custom-field-2</label>
        <length>255</length>
        <required>false</required>
        <type>Text</type>
        <unique>false</unique>
    </fields>
    <fields>
        <fullName>custom_field_3__c</fullName>
        <externalId>false</externalId>
        <label>custom-field-3</label>
        <length>255</length>
        <required>false</required>
        <type>Text</type>
        <unique>false</unique>
    </fields>
    <fields>
        <fullName>custom_field_4__c</fullName>
        <externalId>false</externalId>
        <label>custom-field-4</label>
        <length>255</length>
        <required>false</required>
        <type>Text</type>
        <unique>false</unique>
    </fields>
    <fields>
        <fullName>custom_field_5__c</fullName>
        <externalId>false</externalId>
        <label>custom-field-5</label>
        <length>255</length>
        <required>false</required>
        <type>Text</type>
        <unique>false</unique>
    </fields>
</CustomObject>
```

**Admin.Profile**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Profile xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <fieldPermissions>
        <field>Activity.custom_field_1__c</field>
        <editable>true</editable>
        <hidden>false</hidden>
        <readable>true</readable>
    </fieldPermissions>
    <fieldPermissions>
        <field>Activity.custom_field_2__c</field>
        <editable>true</editable>
        <hidden>false</hidden>
        <readable>true</readable>
    </fieldPermissions>
    <fieldPermissions>
        <field>Activity.custom_field_3__c</field>
        <editable>true</editable>
        <hidden>false</hidden>
        <readable>true</readable>
    </fieldPermissions>
    <fieldPermissions>
        <field>Activity.custom_field_4__c</field>
        <editable>true</editable>
        <hidden>false</hidden>
        <readable>true</readable>
    </fieldPermissions>
    <fieldPermissions>
        <field>Activity.custom_field_5__c</field>
        <editable>true</editable>
        <hidden>false</hidden>
        <readable>true</readable>
    </fieldPermissions>
</Profile>
```

**Folder Structure**

```
-- package.xml
-- objects
      -- Activity.object
-- profiles
      -- Activity.profile
```

I simply zip the folder, deployed it using metadata API via workbench. But the field permissions are not getting updated. I see success in the Deployment Status but there's no change in the FLS of any custom field. What could I be missing?

PS, I am logged in as Admin User.

Comment: I think you need to set the permissions on Event and Task, not on Activity